# How to model following dependent variable in the linear regression framework?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model

I have some biological data of gene expression (GE) in the cells. I want to model GE  behaviour as a linear model where GE in cell Y is dependent on GE in Cell X1, Cell X2,  Cell X3 and many more. Just showing 3 for the simplicity. In the following figure GE of cell Y is plotted against the cell X1, X2 and X3.

[image]

After looking above plot I don't think I can model them as

> Y = b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x3 + c

Do you suggest any GLM (generalized linear model GLM) such as poisson regression can help? Do GLM helpful for such continuous data form. I do not want to explore non-linear model becasue I think it will be difficult to translate into actual biological understanding.

Parameters of Ridge regression(C=coefficient, I=Intercept, p=pvalue,lambda=regularization)
[image]

Comment: what about those plots made you think that linear regression will not work ?

Comment: For example I do not see any linear trend between Y ~ X1. I also looked the histogram of X1, X2, X3 and Y separately and they do not appear Gaussian.

Comment: Neither of those things indicate that the linear model is bad. You shouldn't expect to see a linear trend between Y and X1 but rather between the *average* of Y given X1 and X1. This seems to be consistent with the plots (with a negative slopes)

Comment: I uploaded one more figure where I mentioned the parameters of Ridge regression in the title. If I focused on pvalue then X1 and X3 is significant for predicting Y and X2 is not. While the data points looks very similar in x2 and x3. Either both should not be significant or both should be. That is why I have a doubt that linear model may not be capturing the essence of the data.

Comment: Try a regression and show us the residuals, they are more informative

Comment: I calculated the following things: mu=np.mean(y_train), residual_ss=np.sum((y_train-yhat)**2), explained_ss= np.sum((yhat-mu)**2)
I get the value of residual_ss=37782.89, and explained_ss=1132.72